# How can name-generator be added to context:component-scan in annotation form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm working on updating an older Spring MVC application from xml based to annotation based configuration. I'm not sure how to add "name-generator" to the @ComponentScan annotation.

Here's what I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan({"com.styxrbad", "com.styxrbad.common"})
@Import({DatabaseConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfiguration.class})
public class SpringConfiguration
{

}
```

I need to include my implemented BeanNameGenerator to replace the "name-generator" field from the xml within the annotations. I'm rather new to Spring and I do not know the syntax nor can I find any examples in my research. **How can I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ComponentScan` has a property [`nameGenerator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#nameGenerator--).

Is it enough for you ?

**UPDATE**:

```
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.styxrbad", "com.styxrbad.common"}, nameGenerator = MyBeanNameGenerator.class)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to add but I'm how do you add multiple parameters to an annotation?

Comment: Someone would share his implementation of a name generator class ? I need one that names the beans fully qualified with the package. It's proving to be difficult to search and find for it.

Comment: Here is my cheap implementation of a fully qualified bean name generator: public class PackageBeanNameGenerator implements BeanNameGenerator { public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        String beanClassName = Introspector.decapitalize(definition.getBeanClassName());
        logger.debug("Instantiating bean with name: " + beanClassName);
        return beanClassName;
    }

}

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using the nameGenerator attribute and have the custom generator used for all the beans of the application ?

Comment: See `nameGenerator` JavaDocs: `e.g. the default
  * {@link AnnotationBeanNameGenerator} or any custom instance supplied to the
  * application context at bootstrap time.
  * @see AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#setBeanNameGenerator(BeanNameGenerator)`